# SPARk SQL yml file optimization

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

My requirement is to read two files one for previous date and one for today date. And combined the data from both the files and store it in new file that will has date in the file name.

For Example:  file_24012021.avro is previous date file and file_25012021.csv is todays date file. So after combining the data the data will be stored in file_25012021.avro. AND file_25012021.csv can have max 100 days data.

To achieve this I have written YML as below.

```yaml
frameworkComponents:
 prev_file:
    inputDirectoryPath: <path of the file>
    componentName: prev_file
    componentType: inputLoader
    hadoopfileFormat: avro
    findLastNonContiguousSetSize: 1
    findLastContiguousSetSize: -1
new_file:
    inputDirectoryPath: <path of the file>
    componentName: new_file
    componentType: inputLoader
    hadoopfileFormat: csv
    fixedWidthFileMetaData: |-
    [{“fieldname”: “ID”,”startPos”: 1,”endPos”: 3,”colType”: “CHAR”}, {“fieldname”: “ID_1”,”startPos”: 4,”endPos”: 6,”colType”: “CHAR”}….. for all columns present in file]
    skipInitialNoofLines: 1
    skipLastNoofLines: 1

selectstmt:
    componentName: selectstmt
    componentType: executeSparlSQL
    sql: |-
            select ID,ID_1,…allcolumn from new_file
            union
            select ID,ID_1…allcolumn from prev_file where file_date <= rundate -100

write_file:
    componentName: write_file
    componentType: outputWriter
    hadoopfileFormat: avro
    numberofPartition: 1
    outputDirectoryPath: <path of the file>

precedence:
     selectstmt:
         dependsOn:
            prev_file: prev_file
            new_file: new_file

     write_file:
         dependsOn:
            selectstmt: selectstmt
```

My code is taking more than 1Hr to combined the data and generate the file.

Could anyone please guide me on how to tune this so that it does not take that much time.